# Android Keyevent injection requires system permissions

Tags: android

hi i am using key event injection using window manager
but when i tested this application it gives me error

```
  04-12 18:19:35.794: WARN/WindowManager(58): Permission denied: injecting key event        
  from pid 6290 uid 10039 to window Window{45034880  
   com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher paused=false} owned by uid 10020

   04-12 18:19:35.794: WARN/System.err(6290): java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to 
    another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission

 04-12 18:19:35.854: DEBUG/PhoneData(6290):

  04-12 18:19:36.048: WARN/System.err(6290):     at  
 android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)

  04-12 18:19:36.048: WARN/System.err(6290):     at 
  android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
```

I also give the inject event permission 
is there any way to give a application system permissions.

Answer (score 4):

Only applications that are part of the firmware (i.e., signed by the firmware signing key) can hold the `INJECT_EVENTS` permission. If you are making your own device or firmware, this will be relevant. If you are creating an ordinary SDK application, you cannot inject events.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can't do this, for obvious security reasons. However, if this is for test purposes, you might find the [Activity Testing](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html) documentation useful.

Hope this helps.