# Android - sending intent similar to event MEDIA_NEXT

Tags: android, headset

Is it possible to send some intent like `KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT programically` ?
P.S `KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT` is an event that appear after clicking some media button but I want to send it programically.

Comment: Does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635486/android-keyevent-injection-requires-system-permissions

Comment: I saw that topis but I hope that there are some changes in android soft because this post has been written about 1 year ago.

Comment: The key injection part will probably never change since it would allow you to take control over the device & do a lot of harmful things.

Comment: Even if I want to inject event like MEDIA_NEXT to change music in music application?