# Why is there no InputManager.getInstance() for me? And injectInputEvent()?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop a service that injects touch events to the system while the service interacts with some hardware/remote server. I've googled and everyone suggests using the `InputManager` class, referencing [Monkey](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/cmds/monkey) as an example project to follow.

However, there is no `getInstance()` method for me in `InputManager`! All I have access to is exactly what the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/input/InputManager.html) shows. No `getInstance()` method, and most importantly, no `injectInputEvent()` method.

My build target SDK is Android 4.1.2, and my AndroidManifest.xml file specifies a target SDK version of 16 (I've tried changing the min target to 16 too, which didn't help (plus I'd like to keep it at 8 if possible)).

How on earth can I use `InputManager` like Monkey does? Where are the methods Monkey is using, and why can't I use them?

Comment: "service that injects touch events" does not work. Only the system may do that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635486/android-keyevent-injection-requires-system-permissions it's about key events but it's the same for touch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inject input events to one application from other application. Also you cannot inject events to your own application from within application. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/N5R9rMJjgzk%5B1-25%5D

If you want to automate, you can use monkeyrunner scripts to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class cl = InputManager.class;
try {
    Method method = cl.getMethod("getInstance");
    Object result = method.invoke(cl);
    InputManager im = (InputManager) result;
    method = cl.getMethod("injectInputEvent", InputEvent.class, int.class);
    method.invoke(im, event, 2);
}
catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}  catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I got the InputManager Instance, but it is still no use, sigh!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit late but could be helpful for future reference.

**Method 1: Using an instrumentation object**

```
Instrumentation instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
instrumentation.sendKeySync(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
instrumentation.sendKeySync(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```

**Method 2: Using internal APIs with reflection**

This method uses reflection to access internal APIs.

```
private void injectInputEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    try {
        getInjectInputEvent().invoke(getInputManager(), event, 2);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Method getInjectInputEvent() throws NoSuchMethodException {

    Class<InputManager> cl = InputManager.class;
    Method method = cl.getDeclaredMethod("injectInputEvent", InputEvent.class, int.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    return method;
}

private static InputManager getInputManager() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<InputManager> cl = InputManager.class;
    Method method = cl.getDeclaredMethod("getInstance");
    method.setAccessible(true);
    return (InputManager) method.invoke(cl);
}

injectInputEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
injectInputEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```

Please note that *method 1* is a clean solution based on public API and internally it uses the same calls from *method 2*.

Also note that neither of this two methods can be invoked from the [MainThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/MainThread.html).