# Using getInstance() in java class

Tags: java, android, instance

I am trying to use a third party java class code and I get this error
Cannot resolve method "getInstance()"
and
Cannot resolve symbol "INJECT_INPUT_EVENT_MODE_WAIT_FOR_FINISH"

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Error Image:
[image]

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.hardware.input.InputManager;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.InputDevice;
import android.view.KeyCharacterMap;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Command that sends key events to the device, either by their keycode, or by
 * desired character output.
 */

public class Input {
    private static final String TAG = "Input";
    private static final String INVALID_ARGUMENTS = "Error: Invalid arguments for command: ";

    private static final Map<String, Integer> SOURCES = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
        put("keyboard", InputDevice.SOURCE_KEYBOARD);
        put("dpad", InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD);
        put("gamepad", InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD);
        put("touchscreen", InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN);
        put("mouse", InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE);
        put("stylus", InputDevice.SOURCE_STYLUS);
        put("trackball", InputDevice.SOURCE_TRACKBALL);
        put("touchpad", InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHPAD);
        put("touchnavigation", InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCH_NAVIGATION);
        put("joystick", InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK);
    }};


    /**
     * Command-line entry point.
     *
     * @param args The command-line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Input()).run(args);
    }

    private void run(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            showUsage();
            return;
        }

        int index = 0;
        String command = args[index];
        int inputSource = InputDevice.SOURCE_UNKNOWN;
        if (SOURCES.containsKey(command)) {
            inputSource = SOURCES.get(command);
            index++;
            command = args[index];
        }
        final int length = args.length - index;

        try {
            if (command.equals("text")) {
                if (length == 2) {
                    inputSource = getSource(inputSource, InputDevice.SOURCE_KEYBOARD);
                    sendText(inputSource, args[index+1]);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (command.equals("keyevent")) {
                if (length >= 2) {
                    final boolean longpress = "--longpress".equals(args[index + 1]);
                    final int start = longpress ? index + 2 : index + 1;
                    inputSource = getSource(inputSource, InputDevice.SOURCE_KEYBOARD);
                    if (length > start) {
                        for (int i = start; i < length; i++) {
                            int keyCode = KeyEvent.keyCodeFromString(args[i]);
                            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_UNKNOWN) {
                                keyCode = KeyEvent.keyCodeFromString("KEYCODE_" + args[i]);
                            }
                            sendKeyEvent(inputSource, keyCode, longpress);
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } else if (command.equals("tap")) {
                if (length == 3) {
                    inputSource = getSource(inputSource, InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN);
                    sendTap(inputSource, Float.parseFloat(args[index+1]),
                            Float.parseFloat(args[index+2]));
                    return;
                }
            } else if (command.equals("swipe")) {
                int duration = -1;
                inputSource = getSource(inputSource, InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN);
                switch (length) {
                    case 6:
                        duration = Integer.parseInt(args[index+5]);
                    case 5:
                        sendSwipe(inputSource,
                                Float.parseFloat(args[index+1]), Float.parseFloat(args[index+2]),
                                Float.parseFloat(args[index+3]), Float.parseFloat(args[index+4]),
                                duration);
                        return;
                }
            } else if (command.equals("press")) {
                inputSource = getSource(inputSource, InputDevice.SOURCE_TRACKBALL);
                if (length == 1) {
                    sendTap(inputSource, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (command.equals("roll")) {
            inputSource = getSource(inputSource, InputDevice.SOURCE_TRACKBALL);
                if (length == 3) {
                    sendMove(inputSource, Float.parseFloat(args[index+1]),
                            Float.parseFloat(args[index+2]));
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("Error: Unknown command: " + command);
                showUsage();
                return;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        }
        System.err.println(INVALID_ARGUMENTS + command);
        showUsage();
    }

    /**
     * Convert the characters of string text into key event's and send to
     * device.
     *
     * @param text is a string of characters you want to input to the device.
     */
    private void sendText(int source, String text) {

        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(text);

        boolean escapeFlag = false;
        for (int i=0; i<buff.length(); i++) {
            if (escapeFlag) {
                escapeFlag = false;
                if (buff.charAt(i) == 's') {
                    buff.setCharAt(i, ' ');
                    buff.deleteCharAt(--i);
                }
            }
            if (buff.charAt(i) == '%') {
                escapeFlag = true;
            }
        }

        char[] chars = buff.toString().toCharArray();

        KeyCharacterMap kcm = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD);
        KeyEvent[] events = kcm.getEvents(chars);
        for(int i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            KeyEvent e = events[i];
            if (source != e.getSource()) {
                e.setSource(source);
            }
            injectKeyEvent(e);
        }
    }

    private void sendKeyEvent(int inputSource, int keyCode, boolean longpress) {
        long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        injectKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(now, now, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode, 0, 0,
                KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0, 0, inputSource));
        if (longpress) {
            injectKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(now, now, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode, 1, 0,
                    KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0, KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS,
                    inputSource));
        }
        injectKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(now, now, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyCode, 0, 0,
                KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0, 0, inputSource));
    }

    private void sendTap(int inputSource, float x, float y) {
        long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        injectMotionEvent(inputSource, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, now, x, y, 1.0f);
        injectMotionEvent(inputSource, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, now, x, y, 0.0f);
    }

    private void sendSwipe(int inputSource, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, int duration) {
        if (duration < 0) {
            duration = 300;
        }
        long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        injectMotionEvent(inputSource, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, now, x1, y1, 1.0f);
        long startTime = now;
        long endTime = startTime + duration;
        while (now < endTime) {
            long elapsedTime = now - startTime;
            float alpha = (float) elapsedTime / duration;
            injectMotionEvent(inputSource, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, now, lerp(x1, x2, alpha),
                    lerp(y1, y2, alpha), 1.0f);
            now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        }
        injectMotionEvent(inputSource, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, now, x2, y2, 0.0f);
    }

    /**
     * Sends a simple zero-pressure move event.
     *
     * @param inputSource the InputDevice.SOURCE_* sending the input event
     * @param dx change in x coordinate due to move
     * @param dy change in y coordinate due to move
     */
    private void sendMove(int inputSource, float dx, float dy) {
        long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        injectMotionEvent(inputSource, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, now, dx, dy, 0.0f);
    }

    private void injectKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG, "injectKeyEvent: " + event);
        InputManager.getInstance().injectInputEvent(event,
                InputManager.INJECT_INPUT_EVENT_MODE_WAIT_FOR_FINISH);
    }

    private int getInputDeviceId(int inputSource) {
        final int DEFAULT_DEVICE_ID = 0;
        int[] devIds = InputDevice.getDeviceIds();
        for (int devId : devIds) {
            InputDevice inputDev = InputDevice.getDevice(devId);
            if (inputDev.supportsSource(inputSource)) {
                return devId;
            }
        }
        return DEFAULT_DEVICE_ID;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a MotionEvent and injects it into the event stream.
     *
     * @param inputSource the InputDevice.SOURCE_* sending the input event
     * @param action the MotionEvent.ACTION_* for the event
     * @param when the value of SystemClock.uptimeMillis() at which the event happened
     * @param x x coordinate of event
     * @param y y coordinate of event
     * @param pressure pressure of event
     */
    private void injectMotionEvent(int inputSource, int action, long when, float x, float y, float pressure) {
        final float DEFAULT_SIZE = 1.0f;
        final int DEFAULT_META_STATE = 0;
        final float DEFAULT_PRECISION_X = 1.0f;
        final float DEFAULT_PRECISION_Y = 1.0f;
        final int DEFAULT_EDGE_FLAGS = 0;
        MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(when, when, action, x, y, pressure, DEFAULT_SIZE,
                DEFAULT_META_STATE, DEFAULT_PRECISION_X, DEFAULT_PRECISION_Y,
                getInputDeviceId(inputSource), DEFAULT_EDGE_FLAGS);
        event.setSource(inputSource);
        Log.i(TAG, "injectMotionEvent: " + event);
        InputManager.getInstance().injectInputEvent(event,
                InputManager.INJECT_INPUT_EVENT_MODE_WAIT_FOR_FINISH);
    }

    private static final float lerp(float a, float b, float alpha) {
        return (b - a) * alpha + a;
    }

    private static final int getSource(int inputSource, int defaultSource) {
        return inputSource == InputDevice.SOURCE_UNKNOWN ? defaultSource : inputSource;
    }

    private void showUsage() {
        System.err.println("Usage: input [<source>] <command> [<arg>...]");
        System.err.println();
        System.err.println("The sources are: ");
        for (String src : SOURCES.keySet()) {
            System.err.println("      " + src);
        }
        System.err.println();
        System.err.println("The commands and default sources are:");
        System.err.println("      text <string> (Default: touchscreen)");
        System.err.println("      keyevent [--longpress] <key code number or name> ..."
                + " (Default: keyboard)");
        System.err.println("      tap <x> <y> (Default: touchscreen)");
        System.err.println("      swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)]"
                + " (Default: touchscreen)");
        System.err.println("      press (Default: trackball)");
        System.err.println("      roll <dx> <dy> (Default: trackball)");
    }
}
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364264/why-is-there-no-inputmanager-getinstance-for-me-and-injectinputevent)

Comment: I meet the same question. I look up the Android API document, and there is no getInstance method. You can see this to resolve your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364264/why-is-there-no-inputmanager-getinstance-for-me-and-injectinputevent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there no InputManager.getInstance() for me? And injectInputEvent()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364264/why-is-there-no-inputmanager-getinstance-for-me-and-injectinputevent)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're building against the SDK, not against AOSP. The `getInstance()` method is hidden (note the `@hide` [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/input/InputManager.java#225)). This means the method is not included in the android.jar file applications are built against.

You'll either need to access the method via reflection, or build against AOSP.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used wrong import, can you check if you imported InputManager from correct package, and that is not error , it just compilation error as your IDE couldn't find the references

Comment: Using import android.hardware.input.InputManager;

That should contain

getInstance();