# SDK Android : How to open Shutdown/Reboot dialog for the device

Tags: android, sdk, dialog, shutdown, reboot

I'm new here.

I have a problem, i try to shutdown a 4.2.2 android device (not root).

I know that `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` not works with unroot device.

So i want to open the existing shutdown/reboot/airplane dialog, the same we get when we maintain the on/off button. Then the user just have to click shutdown button.

I try to create by this way, without result...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS); // or others settings         
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show power off menu on android on the click of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614913/how-to-show-power-off-menu-on-android-on-the-click-of-a-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is no public sdk access to open the power button menu programatically. 

This link has all the approches Here.[Simulating power button press to display switch off dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338022/simulating-power-button-press-to-display-switch-off-dialog-box)

Answer (score 0):

```
InputManager.getInstance().injectInputEvent(new InputEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER, keyCode), sync);
```

'sync' becomes either of these:

```
InputManager.INJECT_INPUT_EVENT_MODE_WAIT_FOR_FINISH 
InputManager.INJECT_INPUT_EVENT_MODE_WAIT_FOR_RESULT
```

and you need

```
import android.hardware.input.InputManager;
```

This is untested, but puts you in the right direction, also bare in mind, functionality like this is NOT recommend.

failing that:

```
public static void simulateKey(final int KeyCode) {

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyCode);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception when sendKeyDownUpSync", e.toString());
            }
        }

    }.start();
}
```

and simply call it like

```
simulateKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER);
```

Comment: injectInputEvent not works for my APK, i see that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635486/android-keyevent-injection-requires-system-permissions).
I try simulateKey(), no error, but no result, it isn't open shutdown dialog