# android - How to show shutdown confirmation dialog programmatically

Tags: java, android

I would like to programmatically shutdown the users device from within my app. Since I know it is impossible to shut it down directly, I was wondering if there is a way for me to instead show the confirmation dialog box that would show up if you were to press "Power off".

Comment: You could just execute a process using `reboot -p` - but you'd need root access

Comment: possible duplicate of [SDK Android : How to open Shutdown/Reboot dialog for the device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930790/sdk-android-how-to-open-shutdown-reboot-dialog-for-the-device)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating power button press to display switch off dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338022/simulating-power-button-press-to-display-switch-off-dialog-box)

Answer (score 1):

If your app has root access you can run the following as root:

`am start -a android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN`

Answer (score 0):

how can you see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930790/sdk-android-how-to-open-shutdown-reboot-dialog-for-the-device?rq=1) you can't do this directly, but there are some workaround in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338022/simulating-power-button-press-to-display-switch-off-dialog-box) link

Comment: I wanted to be able to show the confirm box (Your phone will be shut down, OK / Cancel), how could I do this after stimulating the power off menu

Comment: I fixed the second link (that was wrong), it holds your answer