# How to show power off menu on android on the click of a button?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to implement a functionality where on the click of a button the menu of android appear which we see on the long tap of power button, and then the user can choose to turn the device off.

I'm talking about this menu

[image]

I need it to be without root. There's an app on store which does it without requiring root.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jjo.lockScreenButton

Answer (score 9):

I might be late but this is possible. You have to use an accessibility service for that, which the user must allow access to. Also, keep in mind that accessibility services are meant to help handicapped people and not for this use case.

## 1. Create a PowerMenuService

```
public class PowerMenuService extends AccessibilityService {

private BroadcastReceiver powerMenuReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(!performGlobalAction(intent.getIntExtra("action", -1)))
            Toast.makeText(context, "Not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(powerMenuReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.yourapp.ACCESSIBILITY_ACTION"));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(powerMenuReceiver);
}
}
```

make sure to replace `com.yourapp` with your app package

## 2. Register service in Manifest

Add the following under the `<application>` tag:

```
 <service
        android:name=".PowerMenuService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service" />
    </service>
```

## 3. accessibility_service.xml

In your xml resource directory create a file named `accessibility_service.xml` which contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:packageNames="com.yourapp" />
```

Again, replace `com.yourapp`. You should also provide a description. More info here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html#service-config

## 4. Show menu

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), PowerMenuService.class);
    getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.yourapp.ACCESSIBILITY_ACTION");
    intent.putExtra("action", AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_POWER_DIALOG);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Taken from: https://github.com/farmerbb/Taskbar

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.

The dialog itself is a part of the system, and is not exposed to application developers in any way.

You could mimic the dialog yourself, but the framework also does not expose a method for you to programmatically initiate a shutdown or reboot.

If you really want to go down this route, you could also require root access for your application and use [these options for shutting down or rebooting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39194223/1253844) the device.

If your application is a standard consumer application, I recommend letting them shutdown their device using their devices' standard interfaces for doing so.