# How to make a Virtual Power Button

Tags: android

How to use a button to simulate the physical power button like, a button press would open the power menu like this one
[Power menu Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u29P.png)

Comment: I think this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Lock/Unlock screen programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically)

Comment: Try this one - [How to show power off menu on android on the click of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614913/how-to-show-power-off-menu-on-android-on-the-click-of-a-button). Is that whay you want ?